# What is it called and how to put a sentence in evidence

Tags: floating

Newspapers often put a sentence in large font in the middle of the page to attract attention. For example, see this one:
[image]

How is this form of highlighting called? How can I do it? I have a multicolumn document (using the multicol package); If possible, I would like to add a green ruler above and below this text.

Thanks.

Comment: If not, please provide a minimal example.

Comment: Ok, the expression is "pull quote". That is definitely a big help to know what to search. Thanks.